# I have a problem with an update command sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
 sb.Append("UPDATE Users AS u ");
    sb.Append(" SET u.Reputation = (u.Reputation + @Repuation)");
    sb.Append(" INNER JOIN Comments AS c ON c.UsersID=u.UsersID");
    sb.Append(" WHERE c.CommentsID=@CommentsID");
```

It tells me that I have an incorrect syntax near the syntax 'AS'

Comment: Whey you using something like LINQ or another entity framework?

Comment: Please Ask only one question at a time.  Start a new question if your having a different issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You SQL is incorrect assuming you are using MS SQL Server

It should be

```
UPDATE u
SET u.Reputation = (u.Reputation + @Reputation)
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Comments c ON c.UsersID = u.UsersID
WHERE c.CommentsID = @CommentsID
```

Comment: @Matrix001 OK Your comment does not apply.  What DB are you using?  Sounds like Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: it does i think it has SQL server 2005.